# Spring Data MongoDb - embedding a document with @Indexed(unique=true)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have defined the following collections:

```
@Document(collection="sectors")
public class Sector {

    private final String id = null;
    @Indexed(unique=true)  
    private String name;


}


@Document(collection="companies")
public class Company {

    @Id
    private UUID uid; 
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String nif;
    private String name;
    private List<Sector> sectors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

If I try to insert two companies with the same sectors then I'm getting 
`'E11000 duplicate key error index: fake.companies.sectors.name  dup key : {[[sector1, sector2]] }';`

Commenting out `@Indexed(unique=true)` from Sector it works. Why happens this? Is a bug? I want the Sector entity to be uniquely indexed by name and two Companies should have no issues on sharing the same Sectors.

Comment: This is how indexes work. They are unique across documents in collection not in a single document. Look [explanation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-constraint-across-separate-documents) and [workaround](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1068)

Comment: @Veeram oh, well, that sucks. ty

Answer (score 0):

You are currently creating Sectors not as a seperate document but as a nested object. This means spring data ignores the `@Document` annotation and uses the `@Indexed` annotation. Not a sector has to be unique for every company.

However. If you are trying to create a relation between sectors and companies you should add `@DBRef` for `private List<Sector> sectors = new ArrayList<>();`

This way Spring data will reference the sector. Do note that mongoDB does not cascade for you and you have to create the sector before being able to reference it as a DBRef. An alternative is to just save the sector ID and grab it manually when needed.

Comment: I don't want to use @DBRef because I want to be able to access Sector properties when I'm querying.